# Write xmlelement using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

How the below content can be convert to xml using LINQ

```
List<int> calllist = new List<int>();
calllist.Add(10);
calllist.Add(5);
calllist.Add(1);
calllist.Add(20);
```

The output should be:

```
<root>
    <child>
        <name>1</name>
        <count>1</count>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>5</name>
        <count>1</count>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>10</name>
        <count>1</count>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>20</name>
        <count>1</count>
    </child>
</root>
```

I tried something like:

```
XElement root = new XElement ("root", 
    new XElement("child",new XElement(from c in calllist select c; /*error here*/ )));
```

But got stuck up and unable to proceed. Can anyone share a solution to make this work?

Comment: There is an entire namespace dedicated to using LINQ to XML, read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: `XmlElement` and `XmlAttribute` are from the old DOM API. For LINQ to XML, you want `XElement` and `XAttribute`, to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you..I imported Xml.Linq and updated the post.

Comment: Right, now why are you using `XAttribute` at all? Where do you think there are *attributes* in your sample XML? Think about how many `child` elements you want - one per entry, right? (You can think about the counting later). So that should be part of the query...

Comment: I understood. I dont need xattribute here.

Comment: @user833985 -- what should `child/count` contain?

Answer (score 0):

@user833985

Try the below.

```
XElement root = new XElement(
            "root", from c in calllist orderby c select
            new XElement("child", 
                 new XElement("name", c),
                  new XElement("count",calllist.Count))

            );
```

Comment: Won't this make each "count" element have 4 as the content?  I'm not sure what it is supposed to have from the question but I doubt 4 is correct.  I think you want to group by c and then use the count of the group -- but it is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement root = 
  new XElement("root",
    calllist
      .GroupBy(c => c)
      .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
      .Select(g => new XElement("child",
                                new XElement("name", g.Key),
                                new XElement("count",g.Count())
                               )
             )
  );
```